# How to handle the telegram bot api when the user passes only command "/say"

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

If the user calls a command /weather [something], it will run the below code block.

```
bot.onText(/\/[wW]eather(.+)/, (msg, match) => {

    bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, " xd !!! ")

});
```

But if the user calls just the command /weather, it will run that code block.

The reason I know I put the console log in that code block and it only output when the user passes a message to the command.

Is there any way I can handle this type of situation properly?

Comment: Did you mean to say: "But if the user calls just the command /weather, it won't run that code block."??

Comment: @0stone0 exactly